# How are Class declarations and defintions stored in object oriented languages (C++) after compilation?

Tags: java, c++, class, oop, compilation

I understand how the memory is organised for C programs(the stack, heap, function calls etc).
Now, I really don't understand how all these things work in Object Oriented Languages (to be more specific, C++).

I understand that whenever I use the **new** keyword, the space for the object is allocated onto the heap.

Some of my basic questions regarding this are:

**1)** Are class definitions stored somewhere in memory during execution of the program ?

**2)** If yes, then where and how is it stored. If no, then how are the functions dispatched at run time (in case of the virtual/non-virtual functions).

**3)** When an object is allocated memory, what all details about the object are stored in it ? (which class it belongs to, the member functions, the public private variables/functions etc.)

So basically, can someone please explain how the object oriented code gets converted after/during compilation so that these O.O.P. features are implemented?

I am comfortable with Java/C++. So you can explain the logic with either of the languages since both have quite distinct features.

Also, please add any reference links so that I can read it from there too, just in case some further doubts arise!

Thanks!

Comment: In C++ you don't get reflection so most of the info readable by a user is not available after compilation (although some compilers might have friendly names for symbols). I left the Java tag because that's what you're targeting with this question, as it does have reflection.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> 1) Are class definitions stored somewhere in memory during execution of the program ?

In C++, no. In Java, yes.

> 2) If yes, then where and how is it stored. If no, then how are the functions dispatched at run time (in case of the virtual/non-virtual functions).

In C++, calls to non-virtual functions are replaced by the compiler with the actual static address of the function; calls to virtual functions work through a [virtual table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table). `new` is translated to memory allocation (the compiler knows the precise size) followed by a call to the (statically-determined) constructor. A field access is translated by the compiler to accessing memory in a statically-known offset from the beginning of the object.

It's similar in Java - in particular, a virtual table is used for virtual calls - except that field access can be done symbolically.

> 3) When an object is allocated memory, what all details about the object are stored in it ? (which class it belongs to, the member functions, the public private variables/functions etc.)

In C++ - no metadata is stored (well, with the exception of some bits needed for [RTTI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information)). In Java you get type information and visibility for all members and a few other things - you can check out the [Java class file definition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se5.0/html/ClassFile.doc.html) for more information.

> So basically, can someone please explain how the object oriented code gets converted after/during compilation so that these O.O.P. features are implemented?

As you can see from my answers above, it really depends on the language.

In a language like C++, the heavy lifting is done by the compiler, and the resulting code have very little to do with object oriented concepts - in fact, the typical target language for a C++ compiler (native binary code) is untyped.

In a language like Java, the compiler targets an intermediate representation which usually contains a lot of extra details - type information, member visibility, etc. This is also what enables [reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)) in those sorts of languages.

Answer (score 3):

> Are class definitions stored somewhere in memory during execution of the program ?

Definitions are not preserved - at least not in the sense of maintaining the information you have at compile time.

> When an object is allocated memory, what all details about the object are stored in it ? (which class it belongs to, the member functions, the public private variables/functions etc.)

During compilation, things like references to fields are transformed into dereferences of pointers with a fixed offset. For example, the `a->first` might be translated as something like `*(a + 4)`, `a->second` as `*(a + 8)` and so on. The actual numbers will depend on the sizes of the previous fields, the target architecture, etc.

Similar things apply for the size of the objects (for purposes of allocation and deallocation).

In short, **the sizes** of the objects **and the offsets** of their fields are known at compile time and they **are replaced in the actual binary**.

> If no, then how are the functions dispatched at run time (in case of the virtual/non-virtual functions).

Things like virtual method calls are typically translated in a similar way as fields, since they too can be considered "fields" of a hidden data structure (called *vtable*) of that class. A pointer to the vtable of a given class is stored in every object (of that class), if it has virtual methods.

The correct implementations of non-virtual methods are known at compile time and thus these methods can be "linked" on the spot without the use of a vtable.

Answer (score 2):

Details may differ, but generally for each C++ class we have:

- a set of its methods, each method is just a function, and
- virtual methods table: an array where each element refers to a method of this class or one of its superclasses

An object without virtual methods is just a structure like in C. As soon as a virtual method is declared, object gets a hidden field which refers to the virtual table (below, `vmt`).

Invocation of non-virtual method `obj.m(arg)` is converted to invocation of C-like function `m$(obj, arg)` where `m$` is some artifical identifier generated by C++ compiler to distinguish method named `m` from so named methods in other classes.

Invocation of virtual method `obj.m(arg)` is converted to `(obj->vmt[N])(obj, arg)`, that is, actual function is taken from the object's virtual table. Each method has its own number in the table. This number is known at compile time and hardcoded into the invocation instruction sequence.

No other information is saved/used in runtime for ordinary execution. More information can be kept for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the C++ standard to know what mandates should be shared with all compilers. The C++ standard governs some details on how objects are to be laid out in memory. These limitations should be shared among compilers. However, the details are left to the implementation of the language.  Here are the traits I've found common in excess of the standard.

A simple object without inheritance or static fields is laid out like you see it. C++ mandates that memory is byte addressed, but that doesn't mean the data will be aligned to bytes. It will align to the compiler's specification (depending on architecture and other factors). Mostly I've found that data is aligned to words. If you find it packs by words, and you have only single bytes, the memory will have empty spots between the bytes. There is no metadata for an object other than a reference to the virtual function table, if it's needed. When you get to inheritance and multiple inheritance, it becomes more complicated.

Functions are stored separately from the object, and how you cast the object determines what functions you'll call those look at the object as whatever they expect it to be. This all works because in reality, the function has a hidden this pointer as its first argument. There are no run-time checks to make sure you're referring to the right object type. If you cast an object into another object and call a function on it, that function can hit a memory exception. There's no type safety on a c-style cast, avoid them.

Then you have the virtual function table, which returns pointers to functions depending on the type that you are accessing. But again, this is all decided at compile time.

When you get to a langauge that has reflection this changes drastically.

Type metadata is stored for runtime use, and there are type checks at runtime. You'll get exceptions for calling the wrong method on the wrong type.

Comment: "look at the C++ standard to know how it's supposed to be done" - as far as I know, this whole field is actually not mandated by the C++ standard - can you please provide a source?

Comment: Example: 

Nonstatic data members of a (non-union) class with the same access control (Clause 11) are allocated so
that later members have higher addresses within a class object. The order of allocation of non-static data
members with diﬀerent access control is unspeciﬁed (11). Implementation alignment requirements might
cause two adjacent members not to be allocated immediately after each other; so might requirements for
space for managing virtual functions (10.3) and virtual base classes (10.1). |||||

There are some restrictions as to how objects should be laid out.

Comment: Specifics are left up to the implementation. I'll rephrase that to be more clear.